# Error trying to get munin running as a cgi

Tags: perl, cgi, munin

I'm just cutting my teeth getting munin running (latest 1.4.1 on centos) .  It's working but I want it as a cgi frontend so I'm not generating graphs constantly when I look at them a few times a day (obvious).

I've followed the directions and keep getting this error in my log files.  I'm not that much of a perl guru, so that's not helping me either.

```
Can't modify division (/) in division (/) at /var/www/html/munin/cgi/munin-cgi-graph line 111, near ");"
Execution of /var/www/html/munin/cgi/munin-cgi-graph aborted due to compilation errors.
Premature end of script headers: munin-cgi-graph
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the problem...

http://munin.projects.linpro.no/ticket/786

Bug in version 1.4.1.  Port that patch over to the non-fastcgi version and it should work.